# Selenium skips clicking on an element for no apparent reason if I place a different image in the src attribute of the img tag?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, click, imagemap, geckodriver

This is ridiculous. Why does it happen??

HTML source code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WTF</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body id="b">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area
            id="clickhereyoustupidselenium" alt="" title=""
            href="javascript:document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = 'adsf'"
            shape="poly" coords="51,29,155,25,247,87,156,129,52,132,23,78,84,56,104,35" />
    <img usemap="#Map" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="350 x 150 pic">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Selenium test code:

```python
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import text_to_be_present_in_element
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class SeleniumTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(SeleniumTest, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(SeleniumTest, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_wtf(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/'))
        self.selenium.find_element_by_id('clickhereyoustupidselenium').click()
        WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 100).until(text_to_be_present_in_element((By.TAG_NAME, "body"), "adsf"))
        self.assertEqual(self.selenium.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text, 'adsf')
```

The test passes beautifully.

OK, so now let's replace `src="http://placehold.it/350x150"` with a different image, let's say this one: `src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/POL_location_map.svg/500px-POL_location_map.svg.png"`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WTF</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body id="b">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area
            id="clickhereyoustupidselenium" alt="" title=""
            href="javascript:document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = 'adsf'"
            shape="poly" coords="51,29,155,25,247,87,156,129,52,132,23,78,84,56,104,35" />
    <img usemap="#Map" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/POL_location_map.svg/500px-POL_location_map.svg.png" alt="350 x 150 pic">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Let's not touch Selenium code not a teeny tiny bit.

Result? Selenium raises: `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`

And indeed, the Firefox window that shows up still shows the map of Poland, and not 'adsf'. If I click on this area in the Firefox window that shows up until the timeout of 100 seconds passes then Selenium immediately concludes the test has passed. But it was Selenium that was supposed to click on this element!!

What is happening and how to stop this madness?

Geckodriver 0.18.0. Selenium 3.5.0. Firefox 55.0.2. Python 3.5.2. And, if this matters, the dev server is Django 1.11.4.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is size of `<area>` on GeckoDriver is incorrect. Selenium WebDriver tries to click at the middle of the element but size of the area equals to the map. So Selenium clicks on a wrong position. 
You can calculate the position and force Selenium to click at the position. See code below.

```
area = driver.find_element_by_id('clickhereyoustupidselenium')
coords = area.get_attribute("coords").split(',')
coordsNumbers = [ int(p) for p in coords ]
x = filter(lambda p: p % 2 != 0, coordsNumbers)
y = filter(lambda p: p % 2 == 0, coordsNumbers)
middleX = (max(x) - min(x))/2
middley = (max(y) - min(y))/2

action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element_with_offset(area, middleX, middley)
action.click()
action.perform()

WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.TAG_NAME, "body"), "adsf"))
print("Message found")
driver.quit()
```